# Struggling to find the declaration/definition of `Proxied` in ROOT

Tags: c++, declaration, root-framework

I'm trying to better understand the code in ROOT's [RDataFrame](https://github.com/root-project/root/tree/master/tree/dataframe) and the type/class `Proxied` appears a lot. For example [here](https://github.com/root-project/root/blob/master/tree/dataframe/inc/ROOT/RDF/RInterface.hxx#L102). It seems likely to be a root specific thing, since it has methods like `GetTree`. I've downloaded the repo, but I haven't compiled it.

What I've tried;

- Asking YouCompleteMe to automatically find it.
- Grepping the dataframe folder for just `Proxied`. There are a lot of results for this, but none of them are a class definition or a typedef.
- Grepping the whole repository with `grep "class.*Proxied" . -R -I`. I thought if it were defined somewhere, that would get it. No results.
- Grepping the whole repository with `grep "typedef.*Proxied" . -R -I`, to try to find a typedef in the same manner. No results here either.
- I also searched the [ROOT documentation](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/) for `Proxied`; closest match is `Proxy`, which appears unrelated.

I could probably try building ROOT, and then see if then see if the the build logs held any secrets, but that seems a bit extreme for just finding out what this thing is. I don't actually need to work on ROOT right now, just understand how RDataFrame handles `TChains`, for which I need to know what a `Proxied` is.

What tips for finding declarations/definitions should I have tried here?

Comment: i didnt browse all search results but among the first there was no class called `Proxied` only a template argument of that name https://github.com/root-project/root/search?p=1&q=Proxied. In RDataFrame.cxx I didnt find `Proxied` being mentioned at all

Comment: oh you actually also link it yourself. Do you know what a template is?

Comment: `RInterface` is just a template. You need to find where it is instantiated then you know what `Proxied` is

Comment: It's vaguely familiar... I will go look that up.

Comment: its a basic but advanced C++ topic. Not sure how to say it better ;). Using templates is c++ 101, like eg `std::vector`, writing templates can be arbitrarily advanced. It should be covered in any introductory book https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Oh, so actually Proxied is a stand in name for a class that will be chosen when the function is called? Thanks. So the reason I cannot find that is it dosen't exist.

Comment: yes more or less thats what it is